# Set Target Audience to the list using Power Shell Script

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, pnp-powershell, office-365-developer

I’ve a list called “ABC” in root SharePoint online site collection and it have no. of columns. One of the column, say “xxx” is type of “Hyperlink” field which contains the Sub Site URL with display text, like that I’ve total of 30 list items in the list “ABC”, that means total I will be having 30 sub site URL’s. And, each sub site will have the list name called “Due Diligence”.

Now my requirement is, I need to iterate through each entry in the list “ABC” of site collection, and check if the “Hyperlink” field have the sub site URL. If it has sub site URL, then I need to set the target audience for SharePoint owners groups only, to the list called “Due Diligence”, which is under respective sub site, using Pnp PowerShell script/CSOM Power shell script

Could you please help on how to iterate through the list and set the target audience to only Owners group to the list “Due Diligence” if it has the site URL in the list column “xxx”?

Please note that site is enabled to MFA.

Answer (score 0):

We could only set target audience to

1. Navigation Links
2. Web Parts
3. List and Library Items

We can not set audience on list level.

http://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/how-does-audience-targeting-in-a-list-document-library-work/